# Can I pass a different value as a input from using button but display something else in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a list of button which has to **display** the number of comments as the value of the button. But when I click the button I want to **send/pass** the comment Id to the method that is submitted. Is there a way to achieve this kind of thing?

Edited:
What I did was, In the table That I have list of buttons

```
                @foreach(var s in Model.List)  
                 {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left;">@s.ID</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">@s.CD</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">@s.DE</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">                                
                            <input class="xxxxx" style="text-align:center;" type="submit" name="count" value ="@s.k" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="SupportID" value="@s.ID" />                                                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  }
```

This is passing the S.ID to the controller method, But it is not intuitive and I feel that is not the best method to do it.

Comment: Where is your existing code for the button?

Comment: there are numerous ways to do so, but for which you have to show some of your code that you are trying, so that we can help you accordingly

Comment: Could you describe what you want to achive with more details? It is possible, but if you want example, i need to know more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need to pass anything else apart from the ID ?

If not then you can just use a simple anchor and set the URL to be something like

> `href="/Page/Method/@s.ID"`

and create the method that accepts the ID.

Alternatively you can use jQuery to do an AJAX call to the method, you will then have access to any attributes on the button element to then use in the AJAX Call.